# Chrome Security failing for SSRS Reports

Tags: google-chrome, reporting-services

When running SSRS Reports that have many parameters that users will change and click view report to see different results, chrome security will intermittently prompt for Sign In.  When it does, valid credentials will not work.

This started happening with the latest chrome update where the tabs because curved about two months ago.

IE and Edge work fine (albeit much slower)

The Datasource uses a sql login with full access to the SQL Server.

The end users are on windows auth and should not be prompted once authenticated.

Same report has worked for a long time prior to latest update and works in other browsers.  Chrome Canary does the same thing.  All Chrome users are having this same issue rendering chrome unusable for SSRS.

I have access to the reporting services log file, but there is lots of traffic so very hard to read.

I can run profiler, but the server is very busy and I'm since I'm not sure what to look for, leaving it wide open has so many other threads from other users and it seems even my spid changes constantly as ssrs moves through the requests.  Enter report, view report, view report, view report, etc..

Cannot find anything close on google except old stuff that we've went through with chrome using the ie lan advanced security settings. None of the old stuff helps.  Have also check ssrs configs to make sure we are forcing windows auth and it is.

Any help with the actual problem or even help with how to troubleshoot this would be greatly appreciated.

Screenshot provided just after hitting view report for the third time.  Correct credentials will not work at this point.

Ken . . .
[image]

Comment: Can you use the dev console to check the network requests and responses when this happens - it might shed some light.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved as a Digital Guardian network tool blocking.